# Can't access to the variable in object macro after just defining the variable (rivescript)

Tags: python, rivescript

```
# in python

> object tempCall python
   return 'right'
< object

< object test python

   temp_query = rs.get_uservar(rs.current_user(),"temp_query")
   print(temp_query)

> object

# in rivescript

+ xyz (x|y|z)
- <set temp_query=answer is <call>tempCall <star></call>
^ <call>test</call>
```

Output:
answer is {*call*}tempCall x{*call*}

I was hoping for 'answer is right' as an output.

How do I make it work? Am I missing something? Please guide me. Thanks!